# How to get notified when wrong password is entered for logging-in/un-locking an user session?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, authentication, mfc

I need to know how to get notified when login is failed during the windows os is in either log-off state or locked state in MFC/vc++? Is there any API or messages available?

Comment: You could poll the log...

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Can you please explain more?

Comment: You know, use a polling technique to read the Windows Event Log.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott: Do not poll when you can subscribe to events instead. [Subscribing to Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385771.aspx) has all the information.

Comment: @IInspectable Good point. He'll have to [Enable Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.enableraisingevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in that case.

Comment: You will inevitably run into the issue that the Windows Event Log Event Source names are abbreviated. [See how this guy solved that problem while trying to log invalid passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14600302/2596334). It should be the very thing you're looking for.